# Display error message PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am unable to get the last 2 echos to work, even if the update query fails it still displays success. If anyone has any suggestions on this code to be improved on any line, please do!

```
<?php
        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['answer']))  { 
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $idfetch = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'") //check it
            or die(mysql_error());
            $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($idfetch);  
            $id = $fetched['id']; //get users id for checking
            $answer = $_POST['answer'];
            $password = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
            $confpass = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confpass']));
            if ($password != $confpass) {
                echo ("Passwords do not match, please try again.");
                exit;
            }
            $updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET PASSWORD='$password' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' AND answer='$answer'");
            if($updatequery)  {  
                echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
                echo "<p>Your account password was successfully changed. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";  
            }  
            else  {  
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
                echo "<p>Sorry, but a field was incorrect.</p>";  
            }  
       } 
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's terribly dangerous if not used *perfectly* which is an enormous nuisance to do, though I've seen you're at least trying here. You escaped two out of three variables and introduced a gigantic injection hole, though. Close enough is not good enough on the public internet. At the very least you should be using [PDO](http://bobby-tables.com/php) unless you have a very good reason because when using SQL placeholders these mistakes are usually non-existent.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, i appreciate it and i will look into this. I haven't seen anything on it but ill do my research!

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the comments i appreciate it.

Comment: There's several [tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) on how to use PDO effectively. If you haven't seen anything about it, you need better reference material. `mysql_query` is a relic of the 1990s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET PASSWORD='$password' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' AND answer='$answer'") or die(mysql_error()."update failed");
```

and use

```
mysql_affected_rows()

Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

use try catch and try to get the error enable error reporting in php also

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors','On');
        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['answer']))  { 
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $idfetch = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'") //check it
        or die(mysql_error());
        $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($idfetch);  
        $id = $fetched['id']; //get users id for checking
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        $password = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
        $confpass = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confpass']));
        if ($password != $confpass) {
        echo ("Passwords do not match, please try again.");
        exit;}

        try{
        $updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET PASSWORD='$password' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' AND answer='$answer'");
        if($updatequery)  {  
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Your account password was successfully changed. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";  }  
        else  {  
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, but a field was incorrect.</p>";  
        }  

        }catch(Exception $e){
            print_R($e);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(mysql_num_rows($updatequery)  > 0) {
    // success
} else {
    // error
}
```

`$updatequery` will always be true (not NULL), until there is an error in your query

Comment: Wouldn't **[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)** be the right function instead?

Comment: @DamienPirsy is correct. From the manual: [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) - Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query. [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) - Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

Answer (score 0):

use or **die(mysql_error())** as it will display mysql error if there is an error with your query.

`$updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET PASSWORD='$password' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' AND answer='$answer'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$idfetch = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");
if(!idfetch){
  die(mysql_error());
}
```

Do the same for all other queries too.

Answer (score 0):

try this, first count the row count value its great 1 then proceed the login process.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['answer']))  { 
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $idfetch = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'") //check it
        or die(mysql_error());
        $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($idfetch);

        $count= mysql_num_rows($idfetch);

        if($count>0){
        $id = $fetched['id']; //get users id for checking
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        $password = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
        $confpass = (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confpass']));
        if ($password != $confpass) {
            echo ("Passwords do not match, please try again.");
            exit;
        }

        $updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET PASSWORD='$password' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' AND answer='$answer'");

          if($updatequery)  {  
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
            echo "<p>Your account password was successfully changed. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";  
         }  
           else  {  
             echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
             echo "<p>Sorry, but a field was incorrect.</p>";  
           }  
   } } ?>
```