# html form inputs are not saved in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a username/password `<form>` and if false, will display *invalid users*, if true will display a `<textarea>` and users can comment then submit.

basically, the code below, is the `then` statement that *if login is correct then..*

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    echo "success, hi $name";
    echo "<table>
          <tr><td>insert comment here</td><td>poster</td>
          <tr><td><form action='post.php' method='post'><textarea name='content'></textarea>
          </td>

          <td> $name</td>
          </tr>

          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
          </form>
          </table>";
```

in relation to the `<form>` above, i created *post.php* which will parse all data coming from the `<form>` and insert it into the database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("data") or die (mysql_error());
?>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$cont = $_POST['content']; //data coming from index.php <form>

mysql_query("insert into data ('content') values ('$cont')");

}
else {
}
?>
```

what baffles me, is there are no errors being shown.
when I input something on my `<textarea>` then clicked submit, it goes to *localhost/post.php* but when i refresh to the index page, the submitted data was not saved/recorded to the database.

Comment: Why does that baffle you? If the query fails, this gets unnoticed in your code, so why do you expect a notice?

Comment: 1. dont use mysql_* (deprecated), use mysqli_* or pdo instead. 2. content doesnt need quote in the query (its a field name) : insert into data (content) values ('$cont').

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display error message PHP Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909391/display-error-message-php-mysql)

Comment: You should place your HTML outside of the PHP tag instead of echoing it all out.

Comment: thanks @RafH this seems this solved my problem. im not aware that i was using a deprecated method, i was just following a tutorial and just started to apply what ive learned. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are not errors being shown because you do not have error handling method after `mysql_query("insert into data ('content') values ('$cont')");`

So, you should add `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of your query and please capitalize  `SELECT` `VALUES`.. inside your query.

like `mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (content) VALUES ("'.$cont."'));`

So, your code should boil down to.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("data") or die (mysql_error());
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$cont = $_POST['content']; //data coming from index.php <form>

$query =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO data ('content') 
                       values ('".$cont."')") or die(mysql_error());
 if($query){
    echo 'data inserted';
  }else {
    echo 'data not inserted';
   }

}
else {
}
?>
```

Remember though, I am not encouraging your to use `mysql_` because, it is weak and is deprecated, and your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead learn PDO

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a few things are wrong with your code above. Please refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) for help on connecting and showing SQL related issues

Your SQL is invalid, you are not inserting that "$cont" into a table, it looks like your are trying to insert that into your database name "data". Check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for more info on SQL INSERT

Also a few things about what you have above:

- I would avoid using the word "data" as a database name.
- [Make sure your not opening yourself up for SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Just one suggestion. Dont use `<form>` tag inside `<table>`. It creates issue in some cases.
try using below format
`<form><table>...</table> </form>`